# ViewController doesn't show until I quit and relaunch app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, viewcontroller, universal

I have just made my app universal by combining separate iPhone and iPad projects. Everything seems to be working but there is one major bug.

When the iPad app launches it just displays a black screen (presumably the window) and status bar. When I press the home button I suddenly see the SplitViewController as it disappears. When I open the app up again the SplitViewController is displayed.

I can't figure out why the controller only displays after I close and reopen the app. Any ideas?

(I don't have any idea what is causing this so if you need code samples from specific places let me know).

Thanks.

Edit:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [Appirater appLaunched:YES];
    // Registers this class as the delegate of the audio session.
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];    
    // Allow the app sound to continue to play when the screen is locked.
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];


justOpened = YES;
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
      {deleted}
} else {
    [self.window addSubview:self.splitViewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(-2, self.window.frame.size.height-29, self.window.frame.size.width+2, 29);
    imgBar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    imgBar.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    imgBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wood_btm.png"];
    imgBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

    self.splitViewController.showsMasterInPortrait = YES;
    self.splitViewController.title = @"Exams";
    self.splitViewController.splitPosition=280;
}

return YES;
}
```

Update:

By messing around with the window's background color I discovered that for some reason it was at the top of the view hierarchy. I then made the window's background color clear and I could see the SplitViewController. Strangely I can also interact with it. So essentially I have solved the problem by making the window clear. This is obviously not the ideal solution though so if anyone can think of a cause let me know.

Comment: @ryudice no just standard xib's.

Comment: Post your -applicationDidFinishLaunching:WithOptions: method.

Comment: @CodaFi I have posted the method (I deleted some irrelevant code - the iPhone code is obviously not called so no need to post it - )

Comment: I would add the window subview and make it visible in the end of the else block. Can you test it?

Comment: @fbernardo Thanks but I already tried that and get the same result.

Comment: And how are you creating the splitViewController?

Comment: Thats what we need, how the split view controller is initiated. if it's in a nib, need to make sure its hooked up and everything.

Comment: I am using an MGSplitViewController. It is created in a nib and hooked up identically to the working iPad project. When I close and reopen the app it appears and works 100% correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By messing around with the window's background color I discovered that for some reason it was at the top of the view hierarchy. I then made the window's background color clear and I could see the SplitViewController. Strangely I can also interact with it. So essentially I have solved the problem by making the window clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.window addSubview:self.splitViewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

should be at the end of `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:WithOptions:` method.